# why is distanceTo() not enough to calculate distance?

Tags: java, coordinates, distance

I read some code and saw this method:

```
private double calculateDistance(Coordinate coordinate1, Coordinate coordinate2) {
    return coordinate1.distance(coordinate2) * (Math.PI * 6371.0)/ 180;
}
```

Do someone has an idea why is the last part needed for the calculation?

`* (Math.PI * 6371.0)/ 180;` ?

Comment: [Galileo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei) (i.e. the earth is not flat)

Comment: @RC Heresy! Heretic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`6371.0` looks like [the Earth's radius in km](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius).  Multiplying by `Math.PI / 180` converts degrees to radians.

This is turning a distance in radians to kilometers.